# dscl doesn't work from inside re-attached screen

Tags: ssh, directoryservices, gnu-screen, dscl

I am on Mac OS X 10.5.8. I am not sure exactly when this started happening, but I find that when I re-attach to a screen session that was started from an ssh session, anything relying on dscl (directory services), or the underlying getent stuff, fails.

If I start the session *on* that machine in Terminal, everything works. Only remotely started screen sessions have problems when re-attached.

```
$ dscl . -list /Users
>> works

$ screen
$ dscl . -list /Users
>> works

[detached]

$ dscl . -list /Users
>> works

$ screen -x
$ dscl . -list /Users
Operation failed with error: eServerNotRunning
```

Also failing:

```
$ whoami
504
```

I have rebooted, debugged, and googled for about 6 hours now with no luck.

It is really painful since it affects lots of applications (ssh, git, rake, etc).

I am curious if this is affecting anyone else, or if anyone has any idea how to fix it.

Comment: I ran into the same problem of dscl not working and with the same error and not re-attaching from screen made it dscl work again. Thanks!

Comment: I have investigated this a bit further.

It seems if I start screen from a remote login (ie ssh) then screen is set up quite differently somehow. 

Just sharing a data point.

If screen is started from Terminal, it behaves much better.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample within two accounts on the same machine (OS 10.5.8). Could not test it while on ssh, sorry. Consider:

```
1st account = one
2nd account = two
```

Assume being logged to "one":

```
one$ screen
one$ dscl . -list /Users >> works
```

Now while logged to "two":

```
two$ su - one
Password:

one$ script /dev/null
```

Script started, output file is /dev/null

```
bash-3.2$ screen -x
bash-3.2$ dscl . -list /Users >> works
```

That's it ;)

If curious: [Stackoverflow: Why does redirecting 'script' to /dev/null/ allow 'screen' to work while su'ed as another user?](https://serverfault.com/questions/255521/why-does-redirecting-script-to-dev-null-allow-screen-to-work-while-sued-a)

Comment: Your test isn't really relevant; I stipulated in my question that it works in the situation you just tested.